# How can I get the iptables match "ipv4options" working in yocto sumo?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, iptables

Abstract:
On an embedded system running a custom Linux built with yocto sumo, I want to DROP all packets containing any IPv4 options.

Tried/searched:
The iptables match for the options field (iptables -m ipv4options) is apparently part of "xtables-addons" which I can't find as a recipe in yocto.
I would be cool with not even using iptables binary but instructing the netfilter/kernel directly to drop those packets but I can't seem to find how to do that.

Any hints or pointers appreciated.

Comment: Consider to use BPF program for that (see `nftables`).

Comment: Currently using LTS Kernel 4.9.x, so I don't know how much BPF already works with that. Do you have any pointers to more HOWTO for my specific problem (ipv4options matching)?